# what are the disadvantages of not using maven default layout?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, pom.xml

can't we have our own custom layout with a modified POM ..are there any other disadvantages other than complicated POM

Comment: If you do this, you will be losing the benefit of convention over configuration, you will be batteling endlessly with maven, and you will come away swearing that maven is the worst tool you have ever had to use.

Comment: @Rulmeq: That's a good answer! I wonder why do you made it a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean the project directory layout:

Yes, this is entirely customizable (see the [POM Reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html)).

**Example:**

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>sources</sourceDirectory>
    <directory>output</directory>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/compiled-classes
    </outputDirectory>
</build>
```

This sets the source folder to `sources`, the target folder to `output` and the compiler output folder to `output/compiled-classes`.

If you need additional source folders, you can't specify them in the `<build>` element, but you can [add them dynamically with the buildhelper plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).

If you are using only well-behaved standard maven plugins, this should work as expected. However, there may be some plugins with hard-coded paths like `src/main/java` and `target/classes`. Your mileage may vary.